# SSRS: Adding a filter that returns information from entire group

Tags: ssrs-2014

I am trying to create a report in SSRS.  Below is a small example of what my dataset looks like.

[Example Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9fAB.jpg)

So, there are three different stores (A,B,C) and each has a landlord (a,b,c).  Landlords can pay via three different methods (1,2,3) and the amounts paid per method are shown.

Right now, I have two filters set up.  The first is by Store and the second is by Landlord.

What I am having trouble with is:
How can I set up a filter by the Amount that will return information from an entire Store/Landlord?

So for example, if I wanted to filter Amount by 150, I would like to return all the "payment" information for the store(s) that have a payment of 150.  Such as the following:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6fTV.jpg)

Is it possible to add a filter to return information from the entire group? (Store and Landlord are the group in this case)

I am new to SSRS so any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LookUpSet to locate the matching groups, JOIN to put the results in a string and the INSTR function to filter your results.

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Parameters!AMOUNT.Value) OR INSTR(
Join(LOOKUPSET(Fields!Amount.Value, Fields!Amount.Value, Fields!Store.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ") , 
Fields!Store.Value
) > 0, 1, 0)
```

This translates to:
If the Store value is found (INSTR > 0) in the list (JOIN) of **Stores where the Amount is the current Amount** (Lookupset).

In your filter, put the above expression in the **Expression**, change the **type** to INTEGER and the  **Value** to 1.

[[image: 1]]

Comment: This is VERY helpful.  Two other problem I am facing though.  I have slightly modified the code so that a user can type in a prompted amount as a parameter to filter by.  However, if you try to leave the parameter blank the report won't run (saying it can't evaluate the filter).  So, is there a way to make this work so that the user can either leave the parameter blank or fill it in?

Second, when running the report using the above filter it provides all properties with "x" amount, but also gives a few properties that don't have that amount...Any reason why something like this would happen?

Comment: Update:  I figured out the second issue.  Still need help with the first issue though.

Comment: I have added an **OR** to the IIF statement so that IF the AMOUNT parameter is **blank** (ISNOTHING) then it will retrun all records.

Comment: This makes sense in principle, but it returns an error saying it can't evaluate the filter expression only when the parameter is left blank

Comment: DO you have the **Allow Null Values** checked on the parameter?

Comment: I did not.  This has solved the issue.  Thank you very much for your support.